# How do I tell I have Standard or Professional Edition?

Tags: activereports

We're using DataDynamic ActiveReports .Net 3.0 on Windows-XP and we're looking to upgrade to the latest version for Windows-7.  Then we ran into a problem.  We could not tell which Edition (standard or professional) are we using.  I tried Google search adn it wasn't very helpful.  We looked in the "Program Files" and in the "Data Dynamics" folder, we found there's no executable file.  So, we don't know what we have.

Thanks...

Comment: In ActiveReports for .NET 3.0, End user designer control, web viewer control and http handlers were part of the Professional edition.  In ActiveReports 7, End user designer control, web viewer control, flash viewer, silverlight viewer and some pdf specific export features such as pdf signatures, font linking etcs are part of Professional edition.  If you can email us the ARN3 license information that you have, I can find out for sure.  you can email me at rajnish.sinha@grapecity.com.

Comment: Just emailed ya!  Thanks...  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your serial number. The installation is the same for both releases. Email or call the ComponentOne sales team with you serial number (or if you don't have the serail, send the registered user or purchaser) and they can tell you which edition you have a license for.

Alternatively, if you have the product installed on a developer machine already you could try just using the features that are included only in the professional edition (e.g. WebViewer, End User Designer Control) to see if they are showing an "Evaluation" message or not. If they show an evaluation message when you run the product then you have Standard. If they don't, you have Pro.